# Prisma and TypeGraphQL Many to Many Relationship problem

Tags: typescript, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql, typegraphql

I am currently working with Prisma ORM, TypeScript and TypeGraphQL, but currently I am running into a problem where the query with the many to many relationship is not returning anything.

One Category can have many Projects, and one Project can have many Categories:

```
model Category {
  id String @id @default(uuid())
  name String
  projects CategoryToProject[]
}

model CategoryToProject {
  project Project @relation(fields: [projectId], references: [id])
  projectId String
  category Category @relation(fields: [categoryId], references: [id])
  categoryId String
  assignedAt DateTime @default(now())
  assignedBy String

  @@id([projectId, categoryId])
}

model Project {
  id String @id @default(uuid())
  title String
  description String? 
  delivery DateTime
  revisions Int
  categories CategoryToProject[]
  features Feature[]
  reviews Review[]
  plan Plan?
  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId String
}
```

The Query:

```
query GetCategories {
  getCategories {
    id
    name
    projects {
      id
      title
      description
      revisions
      delivery
      userId
    }
  }
}
```

Results (the Projects are not showing, even though there are Projects in this Category):

```
{
  "data": {
    "getCategories": [
      {
        "id": "8933709b-9fe2-422f-a172-2e25904a18b8",
        "name": "Development",
        "projects": []
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Resolver:

```
@Resolver(Project)
export class GetProjectsResolver {
  @FieldResolver(() => [Category])
  async categories(
    @Root() project: Project,
    @Ctx() { prisma }: Context
  ): Promise<CategoryToProject[]> {
    return await prisma.categoryToProject.findMany({
      where: {
        projectId: project.id,
      },
    });
  }

  @Query(() => [Project])
  async getAllProjects(@Ctx() { prisma }: Context): Promise<Project[]> {
    return await prisma.project.findMany({
      include: {
        categories: true,
      },
    });
  }
}
```

Categories Resolver:

```
  @FieldResolver(() => [Project])
  async projects(
    @Root() project: Project,
    @Ctx() { prisma }: Context
  ): Promise<CategoryToProject[]> {
    return await prisma.categoryToProject.findMany({
      where: {
        projectId: project.id,
      },
    });
  }

  @Query(() => [Category])
  async getCategories(@Ctx() { prisma }: Context): Promise<Category[]> {
    return await prisma.category.findMany({
      include: {
        projects: true,
      },
    });
  }
```

This seems very weird; I think I have done everything right and I can insert records through Prisma Studio without any errors, so the relationship is working. It has to be the query and the FieldResolver.

Comment: Please, share the code of `Category Resolver` (`Project Resolver` is useless in this context).

Comment: Oh yes my bad - I have edited the post. But its basically the same result.

Comment: In *getCategories* modify the body to `return prisma.category.findMany();`. Note that you can remove the `await` since the method is `async`. Have you correctly mapped `projects` in TypeGraphQL?